# Append to JSP view using Java

Tags: java, jquery, jsp

I have a form in my JSP which has a list box.
I want on submit of the form, I do some server side validation on and then duplicate the list box and append it to jsp again?

Can someone help me know how we can achieve this  ?

Jsp :

```
<form:form commandName="user">

<div id="primaryList"> 

<select name="data" size="5" id="s">

      <option value=""></option>

 </select>

</div>

</form:form>
```

I know we can do it using javascript, but I need validation done on server side before duplicating.

Comment: you form tag looks like you using spring's form?

Comment: Since you know how to do it in Javascript, you can send an Ajax request to a servlet to do the validation, and after receiving the respons back, do the duplicating of the listbox in javascript.